# Is there a way to calculate standard deviation for each cell across multiple data frames in R?

Tags: r

I currently have a list containing multiple dataframes of similar dimensions.

- Each cell in the dataframe corresponds to a reading of a unique sample
- Each dataframe is a replicate reading of the same data

```
a <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20,10), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
b <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20,10), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
c <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20,10), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
 
> a
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 15  2 15  2 15
2 19  6 19  6 19
3 14 11 14 11 14
4  3  5  3  5  3
5 10  4 10  4 10
> b
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 14 10 14 10 14
2  5  7  5  7  5
3  9 15  9 15  9
4  3 18  3 18  3
5  8 17  8 17  8
> c
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  4  5  4  5  4
2 14 12 14 12 14
3 17 10 17 10 17
4 11 16 11 16 11
5  7  9  7  9  7

sampledData <- list(a, b, c)
```

Ideally, the code would apply to the list created and the end goal is to output a dataframe of similar dimensions, each cell containing the standard deviation of the data from all cell in the equal position across all dataframes in the list.

Comment: If you use `set.seed(123)` before creating a/b/c, you will get the same results every time. It is often nice so that the result can be replicated by potential answerers.

Comment: @thelatemail, Sure! I will take note for any future post to include a set.seed() portion to ensure repeatability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplify to an array, then get `sd` across each row/col position in each set of data:

```
data.frame(apply(sapply(sampledData, as.matrix, simplify="array"), c(1,2), sd))
```

Comment: Thank you for this! The one liner simplicity is definitely a plus :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using two loops -

```
res <- sampledData[[1]]

for(i in seq(nrow(res))) {
  for(j in seq(ncol(res))) {
    res[i, j] <- sd(sapply(sampledData, function(x) x[i, j]))
  }
}
res

#        X1       X2       X3       X4       X5
#1 5.567764 7.000000 5.567764 7.000000 5.567764
#2 4.932883 8.544004 4.932883 8.544004 4.932883
#3 3.785939 9.291573 3.785939 9.291573 3.785939
#4 8.504901 4.582576 8.504901 4.582576 8.504901
#5 3.511885 7.371115 3.511885 7.371115 3.511885
```

**data**

```
set.seed(2021)
a <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20,10), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
b <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20,10), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
c <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20,10), ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
sampledData <- list(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I was leaning towards using for loops too initially, but am not entirely sure how to proceed. Thanks for exemplifying the logic behind implementing such a solution.